# БЭМ именование и структура

Tags: css, бэм

Помогите разобраться.

1) Можно ли в БЭМ делать вложенности `class` в `class`?

```
.class {
  .class1 {}
  .class2 {}
}
```

2) Бывают случаи, когда необходимо добавить `padding` или `margin` одному элементу или к нескольким. Как именовать в таком случае?

```
block
  block__elem
  block__elem_mod
  block__elem_mod
  block__elem_mod # Этому, к примеру, нужно дополнительно добавить margin
```

Как поступить в этом случае, если `mod` для всех общий. Добавлять еще `mod`? `block__elem_mod_mod`?

---

По просьбе Виталия Емельянцева. Уточняю случаи ко второму вопросу:

```
 .car {
      .car__header {
        .car__header_title {}
        .car__header_img {}
        .car__header_name {}
        .car__header_description {
          .car__header_description_span?
          // Как именовать? Уточним что у span-ов есть разные свойства и общие
        // <span>Текст</span> много текста <span>Текст<span/><br><span>Текст<span/>
        }
      }
      .car__main {
        .car__main_description {}
      }
      .car__footer {
       .car__footer_description{}
     }
  }
```

Или:

```
.header
  .header__menu
    .header__menu_nav
      .header__menu_nav_link ?
        .header__menu_nav_link_active ? .header__menu_nav_link-active?
```

Comment: Зависит от конкретной ситуации. Например, если вам нужно уточнить стили для последнего из элементов, удобно будет прописать стили для `block__elem_mod:last-child`.

Comment: удобно, только не везде это работает.

Comment: Где конкретно не работает? Опишите вашу конкретную ситуацию, текущий вопрос слишком общий и на него легко можно дать 5 и больше разных ответов, который, не факт, что помогут вам.

Comment: ie7, ie8 не поддерживают. Я пытаюсь понять сам принцип, решении конкретной ситуации принцип понять не поможет, Вы сами сказали ситуации бывают разные и решений может быть много, вот я и хочу понять эти самые варианты решений.
Если хотите я конечно напишу несколько ситуаций.

Comment: В вашем приведенном примере странно названы модификаторы. "Шапка машины" - элемент. "Шапка машины заголовочная", "шапка машины рисуночная", "шапка машины описательная"? Такие названия имеют смысл и встречаются на практике? Предлагаю вам описать ситуацию, абстрагировавшись от БЭМа. И потом мы вместе составим правильные имена и разберемся в проблеме. Возможно с правильными именами вашей проблемы в коде вообще не будет.

Comment: Я вообще почему у вас все это спрашиваю. Сам использую БЭМ во всех проектах, которые создаю. Есть проекты по 350+ БЭМ-блоков. Ситуация, описанная вами - не возникала никогда, ни разу за все время не было даже намека на похожую проблему. И, мне кажется, у вас ее тоже на самом деле не должно быть. Если освоить именование блоков, элементов и иерархий - описанной проблемы не будет в принципе.

Comment: Хоть на первый вопрос ответьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Модификаторы как модификаторы. Хорошо сейчас добавлю пример, по проще.

Comment: По первому вопросу тогда тоже уточните пожалуйста. Класс в класс? Или один БЭМ-блок в другой БЭМ-блок? Потому что классы в классы можно вкладывать в любой css-методологии вообще ;)

Comment: Ну к примеру у Вас контейнер и в контейнер складывать другие классы которые будут дальше блоками. Так можно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Можно ли в БЭМ делать вложенности class в class?

О чем идет речь в вопросе?

- Можно ли в верстке, или можно ли в стилях?
- `class` в `class` или БЭМ-блок в БЭМ-блок? Или элемент и модификатор в блок?

### Можно ли в верстке..

Да, конечно. Ваш html - это дерево нод, которым вы вольны присваивать любые классы. И следовательно "вкладывать" одни классы в другие.

То же касается БЭМ-блоков. Одни блоки вы можете использовать в составе других, свободно, например:

```
form.form
  .form-group
    label.label
    input.input type="text"
  .form-group
    button.button.button_blue type="submit"
```

Блоки `.label`, `.input`, и `.button` "вложены" в блоки `.form-group`, которые "вложены" в блок `.form`.

### Можно ли в стилях..

Можно. Во-первых, удобно вкладывать элементы в одноименный блок:

```
.promo-section
  .promo-section__title
  .promo-section__text
```

А модификатор этого блока лучше располагать на одном с ним уровне:

```
# promo-section.css

.promo-section
  .promo-section__title
  .promo-section__text

.promo-section_wide
  .promo-section__title
  .promo-section__text
```

Так вы сможете назначать и стили для элементов блока, и стили для модифицированного блока.

Во-вторых, если вам нужно уточнить стили одного блока, когда он находится внутри другого - вы можете вложить его внутрь так, будто он - элемент. На примере с формой:

```
# input.css

.input
  # Общие стили блока инпута .input


# form.css

.form
  .input
    # Уточняющие стили для любого инпута, находящегося внутри формы .form
```

---

## Как добавить `padding`/`margin` одному или нескольким элементам блока

Например такой код:

```
.promo-section
  .promo-section__title
  .promo-section__text Один абзац
  .promo-section__text Второй абзац
  .promo-section__text Третий абзац
```

И вам нужно конкретно второй абзац стилизовать чуть иначе. И последний абзац стилизовать чуть иначе.

## Стилизовать последний..

Может подойти селектор `:last-child`. Например:

```
.promo-section
  .promo-section__text
    margin-bottom: 10px

  .promo-section__text:last-child
    margin-bottom: 0
```

## Стилизовать второй по-особому..

Добавьте второму дополнительный класс. Какой? Зависит от задачи:

- Можно модификатор элемента вида `.promo-section__text_special`;
- Можно блок, чтобы получился микс из элемента и блока (`.promo-section__text.text-right`).

---

## "Уточняю случаи ко второму вопросу"

Первый ваш пример оторван от реальности. Уже писал об этом в комментариях, упомяну и здесь. В вашем приведенном примере странно названы модификаторы. "Шапка машины" - очевидно, элемент. "Шапка машины заголовочная", "шапка машины рисуночная", "шапка машины описательная"? Странное название для **модификаторов**. По смыслу больше подходит на **элемент внутри элемента** внутри блока.

Второй ваш пример подтверждает догадки - внутри "меню шапки" (элемента) вы пытаетесь расположить "ссылку" и "ссылку активную" (элемент внутри элемента внутри блока).

Такие ситуации решаются двумя способами:

## Именование элементов без вложенности

```
.header
  .header__link
  .header__link_active
  .header__menu
  .header__menu_nav
    .header__link
    .header__link_active
```

То есть сами элементы вы именуете без вложенности друг в друга, но вкладываете их друг в друга в стилях, для уточнения определенных атрибутов в ситуациях, когда одни элементы лежат в других.

## Разбиение на отдельные блоки

```
.link
.link_active

.header
  .header__menu
  .header__menu_nav
    .link
    .link_active
```

`.link` здесь - отдельный БЭМ-блок. А внутри блока `.header` вы ее дополнительно стилизуете, для ситуаций, когда она встречается внутри `.header__menu_nav`.

Comment: Виталий спасибо.